# How to fix cross origin errors use React & Express API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express

I have a simple contact form in React and Express API with node, but Every time when I fill the form and click on submit button I receive this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:4000/api/v1/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
App.js:33 Message not sent
xhr.js:178 POST localhost:4000/api/v1/ net::ERR_FAILED
```

My App.js looks like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


class Contact extends Component {

    state = {
        name: '',
        message: '',
        email: '',
        sent: false,
        buttonText: 'Send Message'
    }

    formSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        this.setState({
            buttonText: '...sending'
        })

        let data = {
            name: this.state.name,
            email: this.state.email,
            message: this.state.message,
            username: this.state.username,
            password: this.state.password
        }

        axios.post("localhost:4000/api/v1/", data)
        .then( res => {
            this.setState({ sent: true }, this.resetForm())
        })
        .catch( () => {
          console.log('Message not sent')
        })
      }

      resetForm = () => {
        this.setState({
            name: '',
            message: '',
            email: '',
            buttonText: 'Message Sent'
        })
    }

    render() {
        return(
          <form className="contact-form" onSubmit={ (e) => this.formSubmit(e)}>
          <label className="message" htmlFor="message-input">Your Message</label>
          <br/>
          <textarea onChange={e => this.setState({ message: e.target.value})} name="message" className="message-input" type="text" placeholder="Please write your message here" value={this.state.message} required/>
          <br/>
          <label className="message-name" htmlFor="message-name">Your Name</label>
          <br/>
          <input onChange={e => this.setState({ name: e.target.value})} name="name" className="message-name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" value={this.state.name}/>
          <br/>
          <label className="message-email" htmlFor="message-email">Your Email</label>
          <br/>
          <input onChange={(e) => this.setState({ email: e.target.value})} name="email" className="message-email" type="email" placeholder="your@email.com" required value={this.state.email} />

          <div className="button--container">
              <button type="submit" className="button button-primary">{ this.state.buttonText }</button>
          </div>
        </form>
        );
    }
}

export default Contact;
```

My Api.js look like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const cors = require('cors');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const app = express();

const port = 4000;

app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('We are live on port 4000');
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Welcome to my api');
})

app.post('/api/v1', (req,res) => {
  const { body: { username, password }} = req;
  const params = req.params;
  console.log(params)
  var data = req.body;

var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'Gmail',
  port: 465,
  auth: {
    user: 'pizhevsoft@gmail.com',
    pass: 'pass123'
  }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: data.email,
  to: 'pizhevsoft@gmail.com',
  subject: 'New Request',
  html: `<p>${data.name}</p>
          <p>${data.email}</p>
          <p>${data.message}</p>`
};

smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions,
(error, response) => {
  if(error) {
    res.send(error)
  }else {
    res.send('Success')
  }
  smtpTransport.close();
});
})
```

In the console I see a bug on the cors in Chrome, then I see in the console "Message not sent" statemant. I'm not sure if this code works properly.. but I need to clear this error first to move forward.

Can I take some example how to fix this error :( ?

Comment: Hi, put "app.use(cors())" above all the middlewares in api.js file

Comment: I move app.use(cors()) at the top after middlewares but I receive the error:

Comment: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'app' before initialization

Comment: const app = express();
app.use(cors());
const port = 4000;

But the error is the same..

Comment: Can you update the code here in the question

Comment: I update my question

Comment: Please change your password.

Comment: Try adding header while posting the data to api in app.js

Answer (score 1):

You are hitting `/api/v1` not `/api/v1/:user/:pass`

Change the route to `/api/v1` and send the username and password in request body.

`app.post('/api/v1', (req, res) => {...}`

Don't send sensitive information in params. It will be visible in your browser history and other logs.

```
formSubmit = (e) => {
   //code
   const data = {
     name: this.state.name,
     email: this.state.email,
     message: this.state.message,
     username: this.state.username,
     password: this.state.password
   }
   //code
}
```

```
app.post('/api/v1', (req,res) => {
   const { body: { username, password }} = req;
   ...
}
```

Comment: Can you give me full example for this code.. how to move username & pass in the body ?

Comment: I have added example. Check it out @PizhevRacing

Comment: Thank you I will try and give you feedback :D

Comment: Im not exactly sure what happened in this code:

app.post('/api/v1', (req,res) => {
  const { body: { username, password }} = req;
  const params = req.params;
  console.log(params)
  var data = req.body;

var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'Gmail',
  port: 465,
  auth: {
    user: 'pizhevsoft@gmail.com',
    pass: 'pass123'
  }
});

Comment: move app.listen() to the bottom